# Why does a webpage miss formatting sometimes?

Tags: browser, html, formatting, css, webpage

Sometimes, a webpage gets loaded in the browser but it is not displayed properly. All the elements of the page are there, but they are not there where they should be.

for example (A,B and C are three elements of the page)

```
--------------------------
|       |       |       |
|   A   |   B   |   C   |
|       |       |       |
--------------------------
```

may be displayed as

```
---------
|       |
|   A   |
|       |
---------
|       |
|   B   |
|       |
---------
|       |
|   C   |
|       |
---------
```

that is, the formatting is missing. How does that happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stylesheet might have timed / error-ed out and thus wasn't loaded.

Comment: @Josh K: Is this the CSS stylesheet? What about pages that do not have CSS?

Comment: Then it's a fluke. Something loaded before something else and the browser stopped rendering the page. It happens sometimes, just refresh.